# BASH - read lines and fetch column values using curl

Tags: bash, curl, post

i have a txt like this:

```
ID value1 value2  
ID2 value1 value2
ID3 value1  value2
....
```

I need to send every line as parameter of a curl POST.
Example:

```
curl --data "field1=$1&field2=$2&field3=$3" http://webserver/resource.asp
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your coding efforts to your question.

Comment: First of all im trying to read line by line and print each field. Im playing with awk into a while loop. Like this:

    while read line; do awk '{print $1,$2}'; done > lista.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
while read -r c1 c2 c3; do 
  curl --data "field1=$c1&field2=$c2&field3=$c3" http://webserver/resource.asp
done < file.csv
```